# How to make that native dll is also copied to target directory

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, dll

I  have three projects:

project A is a native C/C++ project which generate a DLL (A.DLL)

project B is a C++/CLR project that loads A.DLL using loadlibrary and made  call to library. It also provide a .net interface for applications in c# to call into a.dll. It is a class library and generate B.DLL.

Project C is a c# project that has a reference to project B and uses its service to call to A.DLL.

Since project C has a reference to project B, it is automatically copies b.dll to its output directory (for example bin\release folder), but I could not find any way to automatically include a.dll to output directory.

Is there any way that I can copy a.dll to output directory automatically?

Comment: You can make this as complicated or simple as you want.  Where simple is just setting the A project's Output Directory setting to the C# project's build directory.

Comment: @quantdev This is not a duplicate. In the SO question, the projects are c++, but here both Project B and C are .net projects. In C# I can create a resource directory and set it to copy to output, but it seems that it is not available in c++/CLR. Is there any equivalent  setting in c++/cli?